Unable to convert address to SDO_GEOMETRY using SDO_GCDR.GEOCODE_AS_GEOMETRY
I have a table containing next columns in my table in Apex Oracle:
location_id: number
address: varchar2
country: varchar2
I want to mark all those locations using SQL query on a map on a page in app created by app-builder.
But since I decided not to create additional columns to store coordinates, I tried converting address(ex '100 Hauptplatz, Berlin') and country to SDO_GEOMETRY using SDO_GCDR.GEOCODE_AS_GEOMETRY. The query itself looked like following
SELECT SDO_GCDR.GEOCODE_AS_GEOMETRY(
  'My_workspace',
  SDO_KEYWORDARRAY(address),
  country
) as address 
FROM pickup_location;


But I recieved a following error

Ajax call returned server error ORA-13199: SRID 0 does not exist. for .

So after that I decided to try to use an example from Oracle Documentation(https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/spatl/SDO_GCDR-reference.html#GUID-D81719AB-9F05-440F-A66E-D40B9A34388C):
SELECT SDO_GCDR.GEOCODE_AS_GEOMETRY(
  'My_workspace',
  SDO_KEYWORDARRAY('1 Carlton B Goodlett Pl', 'San Francisco, CA  94102'),
  'US'
) as address 
FROM pickup_location;


Which returned the same error. So I wonder, what am I doing wrong? Is there a way to show marks on a map using address and country, or I should add another columns for storing coordinates? I was unable to find more info on this one.

"So after that I decided to try to use an example from Oracle Documentation" Please provide a link to the relevant documentation.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/spatl/SDO_GCDR-reference.html#GUID-D81719AB-9F05-440F-A66E-D40B9A34388C
Here it goes

From the Spatial Web Services documentation:

12.3 Using the Geocoding Capabilities
To use the Oracle Spatial and Graph geocoding capabilities, you must use data provided by a geocoding vendor, and the data must be in the format supported by the Oracle Spatial and Graph geocoding feature.

To use the geocoding capabilities, you appear to first need to purchase and install the geocoding data from a third-party vendor (as Oracle does not provide this data); support for this is outside the scope of StackOverflow.
